# Providing username and password on a pop up window when a webpage is opened in Perl

Tags: perl, authentication

I've a webpage which needs to be updated and its a authenticated webpage. When i try to access the webpage, a pop-up window opens to ask for a username and password. How do i provide username and password on the pop up window. I've the below code written but its giving "Unauthorized" error message. When i manually provide the link a pop-up opens and it i click cancel the same "Unauthorized" message comes up. How do i change the below code of mine to provide username and password on a pop-up window and then click OK button on the pop-up.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Crypt::SSLeay;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $username="sqar";
my $password="Pal500";
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => [1]);
my $url = 'http://example.com/content/Jen%20Automation.doc';
$agent->get($url);
$agent->field("os_username", $username);
$agent->field("os_password", $password);
$agent->submit();
print "AFter login\n";
my @links = $agent->find_all_links();

foreach $lin(@links){

    unless ($lin->[0] =~ /^http?:\/\//i) {
            $lin->[0] = "$url" . $lin->[0];
    }
    print "$lin->[0]" ;
    print "\n";
}
```

The pop-up window displays the message:

> the server example.com at WebDAV Server requires username and password

along with text fields for entering username and password.

Comment: Is it basic, base64 encoded authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Try using credentials() method from WWW::Mechanize.

```
$agent->credentials( $username, $password );
```